# How to Get Nfts Collection through creators address

Tags: web3.js, metadata, collection

I am working on Nfts bulkSender Contract. I want to get nft collection through same creators address
How can i gather the nfts which have same creators address. Any help

here is my code !

[image]

this is the output which shows creators of different Nft collections
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get all the NFTs for a creator address?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/6897/how-can-i-get-all-the-nfts-for-a-creator-address)

Comment: Please transcribe the code and terminal lines so that the text material to your question can be searched (ie. by Google and the on-site search). You will likely get more engagement if you do.