# How can I get all the NFTs for a creator address?

Tags: nft, owner

I'm interested in retrieving all the NFTs associated with a specific creator address. I'm looking for a method or approach to gather comprehensive information about the NFTs owned or created by a particular address. If you have any suggestions or recommendations on how to achieve this, I would appreciate your insights - elchuo160

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use the Metaplex SDK with an RPC provider like QuickNode.

Here's an example:

```
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("rpc_url_here"));
const keypair = Keypair.generate();

const metaplex = new Metaplex(connection);
metaplex.use(keypairIdentity(keypair));

const mintAddress = new PublicKey(
  "address_here"
);

const nft = await metaplex.nfts().findByMint({ mintAddress });

console.log(nft.json);
```

You can get the data using that route, but to get it faster without any hassle, you can use a [custom method `qn_fetchNFTsByCreator` from QuickNode](https://www.quicknode.com/docs/solana/qn_fetchNFTsByCreator). In that way you can use the RPC endpoint to call the native Solana JSON-RPC methods too.

Here's the code example in JavaScript:

```
const axios = require("axios");
(() => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };
  const data = {
    jsonrpc: "2.0",
    id: 1,
    method: "qn_fetchNFTsByCreator",
    params: [
      {
        creator: "DznU28LgherhU2JwC2db3KmAeWPqoF9Yx2aVtNUudW6R",
        page: 1,
        perPage: 3,
      },
    ],
  };
  axios
    .post("quicknode_rpc_url", data, config)
    .then(function (response) {
      // handle success
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      // handle error
      console.log(err);
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `findAllByCreator` method from `@metaplex-foundation/js`

```
import { Metaplex } from "@metaplex-foundation/js";
import { Connection, clusterApiUrl } from "@solana/web3.js";

const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta"));
const metaplex = new Metaplex(connection);

const nfts = await metaplex.nfts().findAllByCreator({ creator });
```

https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js#findallbycreator

> The findAllByCreator method accepts a public key and returns all NFTs
> that have that public key registered as their first creator.
> Additionally, you may provide an optional position parameter to match
> the public key at a specific position in the creator list.

Answer (score 0):

Metaplex function might fail if creator has too many NFTs.
If you get stuck with that, you can use metaboss alternatively.
That's Cli tool.

https://metaboss.rs/snapshot.html